# Is it safe to delete The Witcher's save games from Windows?

Tags: the-witcher

I want to remove most of the old save games from The Witcher that I'm constantly generating while playing (quick saves, autosaves, and manual save points) as I know I won't restart playing from these, and they take quite a lot of space* (20+ MB/save).

Removing them from the game is nice because I get to see the thumbnail plus location plus save date, but it's a chore with many of them as you have to select and delete them one by one.

So my question is: can I safely remove them from Windows Explorer, or will it raise issues later with the game (if there is for instance some sort of index)?

---

Note: I'm not really worried about running out of HDD space, but I have an automatic backup running over the enclosing folder (the whole path is C:\Users\*USERNAME*\Documents\The Witcher\saves) and I'd rather not disable it.

Comment: It's been a while, but when I used to play I could move/remove these at will - I played on 2 different machines and I just copied the folder around, or at least the latest save on whichever machine I'd played on last.  I'd suggest moving one to another folder, and seeing if the game throws a fit.

Comment: @agent86 It makes sense, I will try just that and report here :)

Comment: I've tried the suggestion above, and it worked just fine, so I guess it's really safe, good to know.

Comment: It's safe on Mac too. The game seems just fine with gaps in its auto numbering sequence. Fewer saves also makes the Load Game screen open faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, deleting these save files will not cause any issues.